# Save Panel Regression Constant and Residual in Variables

Tags: regression, panel, stata

I am having trouble in storing regression constants of my OLS Regressions. I want to compute daily regressions for each company in my panel dataset; `obs_id` identifies company and date.

I tried to build the following loop. Somehow the saved coefficient is the same for the whole sample.

```
foreach x in obs_id {
    newey retRF MktRF SMB HML if obs_id == `x', lag(0)
    mat A = e(b)
    quietly replace constant = A[1, 4] if obs_id == `x'
    matrix A = .
}
```

I would appreciate any comments or ideas on my code. I also tried `statsby`, but my sample is too large to use that command.

Comment: Cross-posting of similar questions at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1417810-loop-error-when-saving-regression-coefficients Telling people about cross-posting is polite and not doing so widely deprecated.

Comment: I apologize for not applying to the rules and assure you  this will not happen again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but these aren't rules, just suggestions of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is a loop over a single item and could be rewritten first

```
newey retRF MktRF SMB HML if obs_id == obs_id, lag(0)
mat A = e(b)
quietly replace constant = A[1, 4] if obs_id == obs_id 
matrix A = .
```

and then

```
newey retRF MktRF SMB HML, lag(0)
mat A = e(b)
quietly replace constant = A[1, 4] 
matrix A = .
```

What you are guessing or hoping for is not the way `foreach` works. It doesn't look "inside" the variable named to loop over its distinct values. See `help foreach`.

Show us what you tried with `statsby` and/or try `runby` from SSC. Without your dataset or one of similar size and shape we can't test your problem as reported here.